# Always show the tip text of Slider in Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

In Extjs 4.1.1a, How to keep the `tip text` of the slider always visible?

Currently, the `tip text` is being visible whenever the user drags the bar of the slider.
I searched on [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.slider.Single) but couldn't find any related concepts.

**If it is not documented or not possible**, then please explain me how to create the `tip text` manually. The `tip text` should move along the bar of the slider and it should not overcome or hide any other adjacent components.

Here is my code which generates a simple slider:

```
xtype:'slider',
cls: 'sliderStyle',
width: "80%",
id: 'slider',
value: 6,
minValue: 1,
maxValue: 12,
useTips: true,

tipText: function(thumb){
    var months = ['','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
    var value = Ext.String.format(months[thumb.value]);
    return value;
},
```

<strike>Question 2: Is it atleast possible to show the `tip text` when hovered on the slider?</strike>

PS: I also asked the same question [**here**](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?257843-Always-show-the-tip-text-of-Slider-in-Extjs&p=944638).

**EDIT 1:**  I am also moving the seek bar of the slider with two adjacent buttons (`<` and `>`). So, care must be taken that if I move the seek bar with the adjacent buttons then the `tip text` should also move.

<strike>**EDIT 2:** The tip text should be visible when hovered on the slider or the adjacent buttons.</strike>

**Answer**: http://jsfiddle.net/WdjZn/1/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've managed to keep tip visible by overriding some event handlers in `Ext.slider.Tip`:

```
Ext.define('AlwaysVisibleTip', {
    extend: 'Ext.slider.Tip',

    init: function(slider) {
        var me = this;
        me.callParent(arguments);
        slider.removeListener('dragend', me.hide);
        slider.on({
            scope: me,
            change: me.onSlide,
            afterrender: function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    me.onSlide(slider, null, slider.thumbs[0]);
                }, 100);
            }
        });
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.slider.Single', {
    animate: false,
    plugins: [Ext.create('AlwaysVisibleTip')],
    // ...
});
```

Check out the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/554gN/).

Drawbacks of my approach:

1. It relies on private method `onSlide`
2. It applicable only to single slider
3. Keyboard navigation works properly only if `animate` is set to `false`
4. `setTimeout` is used in order to adjust initial position of the tip

Fixing this drawbacks would require hacking not only the `Ext.slider.Tip` class but `Ext.slider.Multy` class and probably `Ext.slider.Thumb` class.

### Edit

Replaced `changecomplete` event with `change` event as `changecomplete` is not fired when `slider.setValue()` is called.

Added [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/WdjZn/) of slider with adjacent buttons.

### Edit2

`tipText` config is no longer applied if custom tip plugin is used. You have to use [getText](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.slider.Tip-method-getText) config of the plugin:

```
Ext.create('Ext.slider.Single', {
    animate: false,
    plugins: [Ext.create('AlwaysVisibleTip',{
        getText: function(thumb) {
            var months = ['','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
            return Ext.String.format(months[thumb.value]);
        }
    })],
    // ...
});
```

Updated the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/554gN/).

Comment: +1 Thank you for detailed explanation which I can't understand though :). I am trying now to understand it.

Comment: You example is great but as I mentioned in my edit that I am also controlling the bar with two adjacent buttons. If I move the bar with the help of two adjacent buttons, the tip text doesn't move.

Comment: @Mr_Green, yep. I used `changecomplete` whereas I should have used `change` event. Edited answer and fixed demo.

Comment: you came very close. the `tip text` is always being one step back. I mean at the previous value. If I slide the bar from value `2` to `32`, the `tip text` is staying at `2` and showing the value `32`.

Comment: @Mr_Green, this is because slider animates motion of thumb. You have to setup slider with `animate: false` as in my demos.

Comment: sorry, working properly when I added `animate:false`. thanks.

Comment: How to add the `tip text` values dynamically from the controller? I mean in the above code in my post, I want to add the **config** `tip text` from the controller side. Please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Please check this post where I asked the same question which I asked above in my comment. http://stackoverflow.com/q/15338960/1577396

Comment: I can't assign `tip text` values on my own after include the plugin you mentioned here. If I remove that plugin, I can change the `tip text` values. Please check the comment added in my post's code to understand clearly.

Comment: @Mr_Green, yes, you have to use plugin's `getText` config. Updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, this is working. Thanks.  I will wait for sometime (check for any bugs) and reward you the bounty.

Comment: The question which I am going to ask is not related to this post. The `tip text` is being visible  top of the slide bar as in your previous [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/WdjZn/). I would like to have it below as shown in your current fiddle. Anyway to position the `tip text`? Though, there may be work around, I would like to position because I need to design the `tip text` in such a way that it should not exceed the slider container when pointing to the starting or ending slider values.

Comment: @Mr_Green, check out [this config](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.slider.Tip-cfg-align) and [this one](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.slider.Tip-cfg-position)

Comment: ok thanks for those links. Your code is working fine in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WdjZn/1/) but when I added this to my project, it is not working fine. I mean, when I drag the bar and leave it, the `tip text` is hiding which I don't want to happen.

Comment: Still this works in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WdjZn/1/ but not in my project. I am doing everything same. I don't know why it is not working. Here not working means, whenever I drag the bar and drop it, the tip text is hiding. for other actions the tip text is working fine.

Comment: @Mr_Green, "...I don't know why it is not working...". I don't know either. Try to debug it to find out where tip's method `hide` is called.

Comment: Ok I will try. Your solution is working perfect but just a minor bug is happening i.e when I drag the bar and leave it, the tip text is hiding. In other conditions, the tip text is visible(working fine). (sorry, I am telling the same story again. I assumed you might not have understood the above comment).

Comment: I still can't find the bug but as your fiddle is working fine, I decided to mark your solution as answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I still can't get it in real time scenario. So, I created the complete project with your code and [**linking it here**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t4ag1403u01bbst/Example%201001.zip). please  have a look.

Answer (score 2):

for extjs 4.2, 
change :
`slider.removeListener('dragend', me.hide);`
to :
`slider.removeListener('dragend', me.hide, me);`